# Python -While loop to recursive

Tags: python, loops, recursion, while-loop

How do you convert the code below to recursive ?

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    fibonacci = [0]
    while a < n:
        fibonacci.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    print ('The fibonacci sequence is : '+" ".join(map(str,fibonacci)))
```

so basically I'm trying write a function fibonacci that receives a
number as parameter and computes the fibonacci series up to that number. 
I was able to come up with the above iteration method but it has to be recursive. 
This is what I have done so far in terms of converting to recursive but it's not giving me the output I need

```
def fibo(n, a = 0, b = 1, fib = [0]):
    if a < n:
        fib.append(b)
        a, b = b, a + b

        return fib
    return fibo(n, a, b, fib)
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: As a side note, calling a local variable `fibonacci` inside a function named `fibonacci` is a little confusing. And, more to the point, it makes it impossible to turn your function recursive—you can't call the function from inside itself, because you've shadowed the name of the function.

Comment: @MooingRawr Oh my bad ..so far this is what i have done :def fibo(n, a = 0, b = 1, fib = [0]):
    if a < n:
        fib.append(b)
        a, b = b, a + b
    
        return fib
    return fibo(n, a, b, fib)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write the Fibonacci Sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: please edit your question (there's an edit button) and paste your efforts as part of your question

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: This is much better. But you should still explain what's wrong ("not giving me the output I need" requires us to read your mind; "giving me [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] when I expected [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8] on fibo(7)" is a lot more meaningful), and where you're stuck, or where you suspect you've gone wrong.

Comment: As a side note: When you get the basics working, you're going to have a confusing leftover bug: `fibo` will work the first time you call it, but then it'll keep appending new results onto the old list, instead of creating a new list. This is because default values in Python are created when the `def` statement is executed, and never recreated, so every call to `fibo` uses the same list. You could try to do something tricky to copy out the result and clear the list when you're done. But a better solution might be to use an immutable tuple, and return/call with `fib + (b,)` instead of appending.

Comment: … or you could use a wrapper function that just calls the recursive function and returns the result. In that wrapper, instead of making `fib` a parameter with a default value, just make it a local variable inside the function. That way you get a new list each time you call the wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

how about this ?:

```
def fibonacci(n, a=0, b=1):
   if a >= n : return [a]
   return [a] + fibonacci(n,b,a+b)
```

[EDIT] Here's how it works:

The function progressively builds an array by adding one element [a] to the result of the next call to itself.

The first line allows it to stop when the target is reached.  Without it, the second line of the function would keep calling itself and there would never be a result coming back from the recursion.

Because the parameters of a function are local to each call, the value of a and b in the second call are different from the previous ones.

If we follow the logic for fibonacci(7), we get:

1) fibonacci(n=7, a=0, b=1) ==> will return [0] + fibonacci(7,1,1).

2) fibonacci(n=7, a=1, b=1) ==> will return [1] + fibonacci(7,1,2).

3) fibonacci(n=7, a=1, b=2) ==> will return [1] + fibonacci(7,2,3).

4) fibonacci(n=7, a=2, b=3) ==> will return [2] + fibonacci(7,3,5).

5) fibonacci(n=7, a=3, b=5) ==> will return [3] + fibonacci(7,5,8).

6) fibonacci(n=7, a=5, b=8) ==> will return [5] + fibonacci(7,8,13).

7) fibonacci(n=7, a=8, b=13) ==> 8 >= 7 so the first line returns [8]

At that point there are no more recursive calls (the first line returns without calling the function again) and the return values start coming back up.

7) returns [8]

6) returns [5,8]

5) returns [3,5,8]

4) returns [2,3,5,8]

3) returns [1,2,3,5,8]

2) returns [1,1,2,3,5,8]

1) returns [0,1,1,2,3,5,8]

One way to think about recursive functions is to look only at the incremental work to be done on the result that would be produced by a prior parameter value.  Most of the time this part of the logic applies backwards (i.e computing the end result based on a previous one).  For example, a factorial can be thought of as the multiplication of a number with the factorial of the previous number.

This gives you the equivalent of the second line.

Once you have that down, all you need to decide is the condition that makes the recursion stop.  Usually this corresponds to the smallest/simplest use case.  For example, a factorial does not need to recurse when the number is less than 2 so the function can return 1 directly.

This gives you the equivalent of the first line.

As you can see in the above tracing, the function will proceed "forward" but actually ends up waiting for a result from itself (with different parameters) before being able to complete the process. This is how recursive functions work.  The final result is typically built when the return values come back up from the stack of multiple self-calls.

Your fibonacci function is a bit trickier than a factorial because the series can only be computed from the original (0,1) values. Unlike the factorial, we don't have enough information to figure out the value of a and b based on the supplied parameter (n).

And, if you'd like to sink you teeth in cryptic code, here's a one line version:

```
def fibo(n,a=0,b=1):return [a]+fibo(n,b,a+b) if a < n else [a]
```

Comment: Ah , it kinda worked when I made a = 0 . Thanks!

Comment: Indeed the modern version of the series starts at (0,1) instead of (1,1). I guess i'm still old school on that one.

Comment: Also in my original iterative method , if the input number is not a Fibonacci it went up to the next higher Fibonacci number . Is there a way to include  that ? i Have been trying to add that to you code but i cant quite figure it out

Comment: Simply change the condition from b > n to a >= n

Comment: Thank you! -It works brilliantly . I'm kinda new to python ,I'm trying to make sense of the code. Please how does the 2nd line work ?. I'm thinking 'a' can never (maybe) be greater than n so why do we the 2nd line?

Comment: This is a pretty standard recursion logic. It would apply the same in all programming languages that support recursive calls.  There is nothing specific to Python in the solution.  See my EDIT for more explanations.

Comment: This is really great ,awesome explanation.Thank you so much . Everything makes sense to me now

Answer (score 1):

The point of a recursive implementation is to organize things like this:

```
if we're at a base case:
    return the result for that base case
else:
    call ourselves with a reduced case
    possibly modify the result
    return the result
```

For the base case, `a < n`, what you do should be related to what you do after the `while` loop in the iterative version. Adding the last value to the accumulator list `fib` and returning it makes sense. It may or may not be right, but it's at least in the right direction.

But in your recursive case, you're not calling yourself with a reduced case, you're just calling yourself with the exact same arguments. That's obviously going to be an infinite loop. (Well, Python doesn't do tail call elimination, so it's going to be a stack overflow, which shows up as a max recursion exception, but that's no better.)

So, what should you be doing? Something related to what happens inside the original non-recursive `while` loop. What you were doing there is:

```
fibonacci.append(b)
a, b = b, a+b
```

So, the equivalent is:

```
fib.append(b)
return fibo(n, b, a+b, fib)
```

Again, that may not be right, but it's in the right direction. So, if you get the idea, you should be able to carry on from there to debugging the full function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Dash's answer is correct, modulo a couple of colons. The original question ask for the computation, not printing.

I've added a dict to store computed values to speed things up a bit, and this code works for me:

```
fib = {}
fib[0] = 0
fib[1] = 1
def fibonacci(n):
    if n not in fib.keys():
        fib[n] = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
    return fib[n]

if __name__=="__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        print i, fibonacci(i)
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 5
6 8
7 13
8 21
9 34
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted the output to be all the Fibonacci numbers up-to the input number

Comment: Ah! I thought you wanted the nth fib number - I see now you did specify the < input number in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**recursion is a functional heritage**

Recursion is a concept that comes from functional style. Mixing imperative-style mutations (like `append`) and reassignments like `a, b = b, a + b` is a source of much pain and confusion for new programmers

```
def fibseq (n, a = 0, b = 1, seq = []):
  if n == 0:
    return seq + [a]
  else:
    return fibseq (n - 1, b, a + b, seq + [a])

for x in range (10):
  print (fibseq (x))

# [0]
# [0, 1]
# [0, 1, 1]
# [0, 1, 1, 2]
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score -4):

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1
        return 1
    else
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
```

Comment: I mean the OP's code produces a list of all fibonaccis up to `n`, this doesn't.

Comment: How about the syntax errors from the missing `:`s?